# Not able to use custom LinearLayout giving xml inflate exception

Tags: android

I am facing one exception in my Custom Linear layout. Please see the sample code below.

```
public class ParentView extends LinearLayout {

    private Menu mMenu;

    public DontPressWithParentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Menu menu) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mMenu = menu;
    }
}
```

When I am using this layout in xml like below

```
com.android.ParentView
        android:id="@+id/call_icon"
        android:layout_width="91dip"
        android:layout_height="83dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dip"
        android:gravity="center" >

</com.android.hParentView>
```

It is giving me xml inflate exception. Please help me.

Comment: Do you have "<" sign before `com.android.ParentView`? Also seems like your `ParentView` class has constructor with wrong name `DontPressWithParentView` instead of ParentView

Comment: an unwanted "h" before parentView in the close tag..

Comment: I have given sample code. In my code constructor is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the following constructors in your Viewcode:

```
public ParentView(Context context) {
  super(context);
}

public ParentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
}

public ParentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@TargetApi (Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public ParentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}
```

Furthermore please check if your package declaration in your xml is correct:

```
com.android.ParentView
```

It sounds a bit weird to me.

Comment: package declaration was sample pkg. Your solution worked fine.